# I use robotframework and selenium2library, how can I do a upload file test by clicking a button?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I want to upload a file by clicking on the button,  when I click this button it will popup a file select window by windows, but as i know, selenium2Library can't handle the window of windows, so input path is diffcult, how can i do?

i tried simulate Keyboard Events to input path before, but sometimes it is not working.

the html source is below

```
<button title="Upload XML file of creation parameters" class="btn" type="button" id="ca_upload">Load file</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use choose file keyword from selenium2library. It accepts two argument first locator for the button and second takes the file path which needs to be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium2 library does not handle those windows. You can use [AutoIT library](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework-autoitlibrary/) for selecting the file for upload.